# most liked / most commented posts in highlighted content does not work

Tags: comments, like, search-schema

I was reading this page where I found out the internal names for likes and comment counts in modern pages (communication sites) using a highlighted content with CAML query

https://www.eliostruyf.com/getting-likes-and-comments-from-modern-pages/

and used a CAML editor to find the code to get all pages that have at least one like or one comment.

The query produces all results of all pages.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: what source are you selecting in the HQWP? I've noticed this: "This site and This site collection uses KQL query strings.  Document library and Pages library on this site uses CAML query strings. "

Comment: the page library since I was able to build the CAML query, I am unable to build the KQL query so I tried what was easier

Comment: i wrote already *several times* that I am working with pages and comments and likes in pages, why you keep bringing up that it does not work for documents?

Comment: My bad, Susan. Sorry, I haven't read your comment carefully. I am fairly busy and don't have much time to read thoroughly.

Comment: Have you tried to execute your CAML query in any tool/code that is not Highlighted content? Does it produce any results?

Answer (score 0):

My observations:

- _CommentCount and _LikeCount must first exist on the list item. To verify it, try adding these to the view. If you can't - then it's a problem
- If your CAML query 1) refers to `_CommentCount` and `_LikeCount` and 2) returns 0 items - HQWP will actually return everything. I think, it's a bug.
- Different sources use different Queries. Document Library, for example, uses CAML and "This site collection" source" uses KQL

[image]

[image]

There is nothing wrong with the Query you used. It works fine in lists where _LikeCount and _CommentCount exist:

[image]

[image]

Comment: there are some comments and some likes, I am not picky and i would be happy to have a roll up that shows pages that either have 1 like or more or 1 comment or more, so it will have to be related with OR. However, it is still not working

Comment: if there are some comments and likes, can you add these columns to the List view?

Comment: they are there by default

Comment: With my query builder I was not able to write a condition such as "greater than zero" therefore I selected 'is not null' but if the likes are ZERO maybe the system considers ZERO as 'not null' and maybe this is why I am not getting results. What is the right CAML for greater than zero? my query builder does not let me use that for this field

Comment: Try a different Caml builder. I have constructed this one and it works fine: ```<Where>
    <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name="_LikeCount" />
        <Value Type="Integer">0</Value>
    </Gt>
</Where>``` I'm using CamlJS Console: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/camljs-console/ohjcpmdjfihchfhkmimcbklhjdphoeac?hl=en  Here is a quck demo: https://imgur.com/L0uvxdW

Comment: I have copy pasted your code, it is still showing all pages, while only 2 have likes