# Sharepoint Modern - Highlighted Contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml, modern-pages, kql, highlighted-content-web-part

Ive been searching for awhile for this.
Is anyone here successfully create a filter in Modern Sharepoint

To show Pages that **Logged-in User Liked?**

[image]

the modern sharepoint can query using KQL or CAML but im not really familiar with it.

Thanks!

Comment: try out the REST api this would involve simple js cewp webpart? refer [here](https://www.eliostruyf.com/getting-likes-and-comments-from-modern-pages/)

Comment: @SudheerChittuluri, OP is using a Modern SPO page, there is no CEWP.  Looks like Custom SPFx is the only way to get this information on a page.

Comment: @willman You are correct, I was looking at this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268462/most-liked-most-commented-posts-in-highlighted-content-does-not-work) It seems like atleast a page needs to have likes for the query to filter the correct pages. I am currently testing it out to see if we can get it. Will post an update here.

Comment: @ssspfx Yes im using modern SPO. 

Im seeing a property card "LikeCount" is there a way to filter all the pages the user(loggedon) likes?